# C integer division and floor

Tags: c, integer, division, integer-division, floor

In C, is there a difference between integer division a/b and floor(a/b) where both a and b are integers?
More specifically what happens during both processes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the behavior of integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`a/b` does integer division. If either `a` or `b` is negative, the result depends on the compiler (rounding can go toward zero or toward negative infinity in pre-C99; in C99+, the rounding goes toward 0). The result has type `int`. `floor(a/b)` does the same division, converts the result to double, discards the (nonexistent) fractional part, and returns the result as a double.

Comment: In C integer division performs truncation towards zero. This is true since C99, before it was implementation-defined.

Comment: Ah, missed the `C` tag. Still, it's clear that my answer is about C++. `<g>`

Comment: @Mysticial the point is that `floor` doesn't round anything in this instance because `a / b` performs integer division and *then* passes it to `floor`.

Comment: `-4 / 3 == -1` while `floor(-4 / 3) == -2`

Answer (score 9):

`floor` returns a `double` while `a / b` where both `a` and `b` are integers yields an integer value.

With the correct cast the value is the same.

If `typeof` operator existed in C (it does not) we would have:

```
(typeof (a /b)) floor(a / b) == a / b
```

**EDIT:** Now if the question is: is there any difference between:

```
(double) (a / b)
```

and

```
floor(a / (double) b)
```

the answer is yes. The results differ with respect to negative values.

Comment: update: c23 introduced typeof https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/keyword/typeof

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to lose information converting from integer to floating point. Not likely with int and double, but with slight alteration:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned long long a = 9000000000000000003;
    unsigned long long b = 3;
    printf("a/b = %llu\n", a/b);
    printf("floor(a/b) = %f\n", floor(a/b));
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
a/b = 3000000000000000001
floor(a/b) = 3000000000000000000.000000
```

Comment: A double can store all 32bit integer values exactly. You can always use double instead of int. It's not just unlikely to lose precision, its impossible. Your example is correct, but misleading people who don't understand the problem yet.

Answer (score 3):

In general, assuming that the integers are representable in both the integer and the floating-point types, there isn't a difference, but the proof is not obvious. The problem is that in floating-point, a rounding occurs in the division a/b, so that the floor function doesn't apply on the exact rational value, but on an approximate value. I had written a paper on the subject: https://www.vinc17.net/research/publi.html#Lef2005b

In short, the result I've obtained is that if a - b is exactly representable in the floating-point system, then floor(a/b), where a and b are floating-point numbers (with integer values), gives the same result as the integer division a/b.