# why is if(1/10) and if(0.1) have different values?

Tags: c

Just do not understand why the following two have different values. The first one has value 0, while the other has value 1

```
if(1/10);
if(0.1);
```

Comment: Related: [C integer division and floor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240228/c-integer-division-and-floor).

Comment: do if(1/10.0) or if(1.0/10) or if(1.0/10.0) and it will give you 0.1 as division will be done with floating point values.

Comment: you can also use `1f/10`

Comment: ... or `1./10` or `1/10.`.

Answer (score 12):

By default the type of `1` is `int`, thus `1/10` will be rounded down to `0` which is equivalent to `false`. While `0.1` has some bits set and is not `0`.

On the other hand `1.0/10` is equivalent to `0.1`.

Comment: I think it's good to note, that even `1.0/10` and `0.1` are not necessarely equal, because of floating point numbers representation features.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(condition)
```

Here the `condition` is executed and checked with 0. If that is 0 that means `false` else that means `true`. 1/10 gives value 0 which is equal to 0 ( as integer/integer gives integer result) so condition failes, where as 0.1 is not equal to 0, so it is treated as `true` and currespoinding statements in `if` block will be executed.