# Mod with negative numbers gives a negative result in Java and C

Tags: java, c, math, modulo

Let's say I have `(-5) mod 8`.

I tried it in both languages Java and C, and they gave me a `-5` result when I was expecting `3`.

Why is this happening? Can a modulus be negative? And what should I change to get the correct result?

**Java code**

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x;
        x = -5%8;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

**C code**

```
int main(){
    int x;
    x = -5%8;
    printf("%d", x);
}
```

**OUTPUTS**

[image]

Comment: In Java you can use `Math.floorMod(dividend, divisor)`. I have no clue about C (and you should probably open two separate questions when asking about two completely different programming languages).

Comment: `(8 * -1) + 3 = -5`; `(8 * 0) - 5 = -5` there's no rule about which to choose in c89.

Comment: @pmg The latest C standard states that `((a/b)*b + a%b) == a` must be true, if `a/b` can be represented.  That rules out `3` as the remainder when `a == -5` and `b == 8` because `-5/8` is `0`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does C++ output negative numbers when using modulo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11630321/why-does-c-output-negative-numbers-when-using-modulo)

Comment: [Does either ANSI C or ISO C specify what -5 % 10 should be?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3609572/995714), [Modulo operation with negative numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11720656/995714), [Why is the behavior of the modulo operator (%) different between C and Ruby for negative integers?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24074869/995714)

Comment: **C89** has this text: "If either operand is negative, whether the result of the `/` operator is the largest integer less than the algebraic quotient or the smallest integer greater than the algebraic quotient is **implementation-defined**, as is the sign of the result of the `%` operator." C99 and later have made quotient and modulus perfectly defined with "truncation towards zero".

Comment: Short answer: `%` is not `mod`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `%` operator is treated as a remainder operator, so the sign of the result is the same as that of the dividend.

If you want a modulo function, you can do something like this:

```
int mod(int a, int b)
{
    int ret = a % b;
    if (ret < 0)
        ret += b;
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: yes but this one returns 5, the correct modulo is 3

Answer (score 2):

> Why is this happening?

It's defined that way in C.  `%` is the remainder operator.  Per **6.5.5 Multiplicative Operators**, paragraph 6 of [the C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> When integers are divided, the result of the `/` operator is the
>   algebraic quotient with any fractional  part  discarded. If  the 
>   quotient `a/b` is  representable,  the  expression `(a/b)*b  +  a%b`
>   shall  equal `a` ;  otherwise,  the  behavior  of  both `a/b` and
>   `a%b` is undefined.

It's also defined that way in Java.  Per **15.17.3. Remainder Operator %** of [the Java 8 specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3):

> The binary % operator is said to yield the remainder of its operands
>   from an implied division; the left-hand operand is the dividend and
>   the right-hand operand is the divisor.
>
> In C and C++, the remainder operator accepts only integral operands,
>   but in the Java programming language, it also accepts floating-point
>   operands.
>
> The remainder operation for operands that are integers after binary
>   numeric promotion (§5.6.2) produces a result value such that
>   (a/b)*b+(a%b) is equal to a.
>
> This identity holds even in the special case that the dividend is the
>   negative integer of largest possible magnitude for its type and the
>   divisor is -1 (the remainder is 0).
>
> **It follows from this rule that the result of the remainder operation can be negative only if the dividend is negative, and can be positive
>   only if the dividend is positive. Moreover, the magnitude of the
>   result is always less than the magnitude of the divisor.**

So the remainder - the result of the `%` operator - must have the same sign as the dividend - the first value, before the `%` operator.

Answer (score 0):

You should have look at Stack Overflow question *[What's the difference between “mod” and “remainder”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683563/whats-the-difference-between-mod-and-remainder)*.

To get mod positive do -

C Code -

```
int main(){
    int a, b;
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    int rem  = a%b;
    if (rem<0)
        rem += b;
    printf("%d", rem);
    return 0;
}
```

Similar would be the Java code.

Basically the approach is that first take `mod` irrespective of the sign (to make the magnitude of the answer less than that of divisor), and if the answer is negative then add the divisor to it.

Answer (score -1):

It's not about the number is being negative or positive. `5%8` would return `5` because that's how `mod` operator works.

If you want `3` or `-3` as result, you need to do `8%5` or `-8%5` respectively.

[Here's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) the documentation, this is what it says:

> divides one operand by another and returns the remainder as its
>   result.

So, it's always fir operand divided by second. Also, if you want positive result then you can do:

```
Math.abs(-8%5);
```

Comment: Also if you only want positive results you can take the absolute value using `Math.abs()`

Comment: He means `(-5) % 8` not `-(5 % 8)`.

Comment: @pmg I have updated the answer with example and documentation.

Comment: but (-8) mod 5 equals to 2 and Math.abs(-8%5); gives 3

Comment: @John (-8) mod 5 equals to 3 and not 2. Perhaps you are trying to do something else and not `mod`?

Comment: @DarshanMehta -8 = 2 * -5 +2

Comment: @John `-8 = (1 * -5) -3` as well, and that's how `mod` operator works.

Comment: @DarshanMehta what is -3? modulo can't be negative.

Comment: @John did you read tons of other duplicates? those answers have already explained clearly that C doesn't have a modulo operator. It only has **remainder** operator

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc sure but in my question i provided two different codes for two different languages well explained with the output results and i also ask for a modulo code that works to help me with my project. I don't understand the downvotes and your duplicates. Nobody in your duplicates provides an answer about a modulo code that works.

Comment: then you didn't read all the answers carefully. there are a lot of working solutions

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc maybe, thanks for your time sir, have a nice day